# Adding a remote repo - Git add remote - Beanstalk

Tags: git, repository, git-remote

I just added a remote (repo?) using the command:

```
  git remote add my_remote_repo git@abc.beanstalkapp.com:/g_my_remote.git
```

I was expecting this Repo to show up in the beanstalk. Or may be I am missing/not understanding something here. I am new to git.

The above command was successful and it shows up along with the other repos.

```
  git remote -v
```

When you say `remote` are we talking about new repo (as I am assuming)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To git, a remote is just another repository that it knows about. In effect, remotes are like aliases to repository URLs. When you add a remote, you are only adding to the list of repositories that your repository knows about (tracks branches of). These repositories must exist before git can use them. You must add a repository to beanstalkapp.com via their web interface before you can link it to your own repository as a remote. The `git remote` command performs no repository initialization.

As their name suggests, remotes are often in remote locations, but they are not necessarily remote. A remote can be a repository on your local machine. If you run the command `git remote add local ../my_repo_copy`, you will see that git does not make a new repository at that location. To do that, you must first make a directory at `../my_repo_copy`, change into it (`cd ../my_repo_copy`), and initialize it as a new git repository (`git init`). Once you have initialized the new repository in that manner, you can use it as a remote to your original repository.

Comment: So are you saying its an alias to the existing remote repo?